# Vue Draggable Next missing template or render function

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3, vuedraggable

I'm trying to use Vue Draggable Next for a Vue 3 example page.

I've followed guide in the [repo](https://github.com/SortableJS/vue.draggable.next#installation). After failing to import Vue Draggable Next component, I've started using https://unpkg.com/vue-draggable-next@2.1.1/dist/vue-draggable-next.global.js instead of https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Vue.Draggable/4.0.0/vuedraggable.umd.min.js.

My HTML code is shown in this JSFiddle:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Sortable/1.14.0/Sortable.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-draggable-next@2.1.1/dist/vue-draggable-next.global.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="item in bbcourses" :key="item.id">
          <div style="border: 1px #000 solid">{{ item.name }}</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li
          v-for="item in pcourses"
          :key="item.id"
          style="border: 1px #000 solid"
        >
          {{ item.name }}
        </li>
      </ul>
      <draggable
        :list="pcourses"
        group="people"
        @start="log"
        @end="log"
        itemKey="id"
        @change="log"
      >
        <div
          v-for="element in list"
          :key="element.name"
          style="border: 1px #000 solid"
        >
          {{ element.name }}{{ element.id }}
        </div>
      </draggable>
    </div>

    <script>
      const app = Vue.createApp({
        data() {
          return {
            drag: false,
            message: "Hello Vue!",
            bbcourses: [
              { id: 1, name: "First course" },
              { id: 2, name: "Second course" },
            ],
            pcourses: [
              { id: 1, name: "First course" },
              { id: 2, name: "Second course" },
            ],
          };
        },
        methods: {
          log(event) {
            console.log(event);
          },
        },
      });
      app.component("draggable", VueDraggableNext);
      app.mount("#app");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Provide error: `"[Vue warn]: Component is missing template or render function."` and doesn't show the draggable list.

Answer (score 5):

I finally found the solution to the problem!

You need to replace this line

```
app.component("draggable", VueDraggableNext);
```

with this line

```
app.component("draggable", VueDraggableNext["VueDraggableNext"]);
```

Comment: I just found out myself after a long search. You could also write
`app.component("draggable", VueDraggableNext.VueDraggableNext);`