# Using third-party components, without build tools

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to add [Vue.Draggable](https://github.com/SortableJS/vue.draggable.next) to my app. The documentation provides a direct link to the javascript files which I import, but I get the error:

```
The requested module 'vuedraggable' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

(the listed source returns a 404, but using [unpkg](https://unpkg.com/) I can get the right file from a different source)

Which I recognize as well... not specifying a default. Which implies I need to import a named package. But I can't for the life of me figure out how to get it to work with VueDraggable.

Here's how I import vue & vuedraggable:

```
<script type="importmap">
    {
        "imports": {
        "vue": "https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.esm-browser.js",
        "vuedraggable": "https://unpkg.com/vuedraggable@4.1.0/dist/vuedraggable.umd.min.js"
        }
    }
</script>
```

how I import vuedraggable to the app;

```
import draggable from "vuedraggable";
```

and hook it to vue;

```
components: {
            draggable
},
```

[This question is very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71111488/vue-draggable-next-missing-template-or-render-function), but I don't understand how to do it without build tools.

What am I missing?

Comment: You can't do this as UMD can't be used as ES modules without build tools. If the package doesn't provide .esm build, you're out of luck. Use regular <script> if you may. A lot of third-party Vue libs can't be used without build tools at all